# Dealing with Foreign Key constraints when loading large data from 2 CSV Files

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a project with mySQL(8.0.19) The task requires the creation of various tables, with appropriate referential constraints and then filling them with large amounts of data to perform queries and other functions.

I've got 2 large CSV files with around 5000+ rows of data. Table B has a Foreign Key pointing to Table A, i.e. when creating Table B:

```
CREATE TABLE B(
       abc VARCHAR(20),
       sampleName VARCHAR(20),
       ...
       PRIMARY KEY(abc)
       FOREIGN KEY(sampleName) REFERENCES A(Name)
           ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT
       );
```

Now, the problem I'm encountering is that there are several values for attribute `sampleName` in the second CSV file, but many of them don't have a corresponding `Name` in the first CSV file. So I'm encountering a FK constraint error when I attempt to load the data into Table B.

I've been searching endlessly for a method in excel to compare two different columns and remove any non-matching values but so far to no avail. One option I have considered is to turn off FK checks completely, load the data into Table 2 and then write up a `DELETE` query to remove any non-matching values. However, I'd much rather prefer if I could alter my `INSERT` query in some way so that a tuple is only added when `sampleName` from CSV2 has an equal value for `Name` in Table A.

Edit: I'm using python to go through the CSVS and add data to my tables, the query is as follows:

```
Q = "INSERT INTO TABLE(a, b, c, d, e) 
       VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
    
    ... #CSV processing into X, MYSQL connection

   cursor1.execute(Q, X)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `IGNORE` option when you insert to table B. This means don't throw an error if the insert fails, just keep going. If the insert is inserting multiple rows, just skip the rows that fail, and insert those that succeed.

LOAD DATA INFILE has an IGNORE option too.

Demo, tested on MySQL 8.0.31:

```
mysql> create table A ( name varchar(20) primary key);
mysql> insert into A values ('bill');

mysql> insert into b values ('abc1', 'bill'), ('abc2', 'john');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`b`, CONSTRAINT `b_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sampleName`) REFERENCES `a` (`name`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE RESTRICT)
```

This is expected, of course. The statement fails, and the table is empty.

```
mysql> select * from b;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

Now test with `ignore`:

```
mysql> insert ignore into b values ('abc1', 'bill'), ('abc2', 'john');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> select * from b;
+------+------------+
| abc  | sampleName |
+------+------------+
| abc1 | bill       |
+------+------------+
```

The row that succeeds was inserted, and the row that had the error is skipped.

Comment: Sorry, this only ignores duplicate unique keys, not missing foreign keys.

Comment: @Barmar, I tested it. See above.

Comment: OK, the documentation is wrong, it says in multiple places that this just skips duplicates.

Comment: Yeah, I admit it does not give a comprehensive list of errors that are ignored, it only says, "This keyword causes the server to downgrade certain types of errors and generate warnings instead." It gives examples for duplicate keys and NOT NULL violations, but not foreign key violations. Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#ignore-effect-on-execution This is probably a consequence from the fact that foreign keys are not supported for all storage engines in MySQL.

Comment: **LOAD DATA, LOAD XML: With IGNORE, rows that duplicate an existing row on a unique key value are discarded.** Although I think in the documentation of `LOAD DATA` it says that its `IGNORE` is treated like `INSERT`.

Comment: That's true, but rows that cause any other kind of error can't be inserted either.

Comment: I've tested this two ways, turned FK constraints off and all the data is loaded into the table. This tells me there aren't any syntax errors or such present. Turned FK constraints back on and added an IGNORE, the program doesn't show any errors but the table is an Empty Set. Do you have any idea why this would happen?

Comment: That sounds like none of the rows contained a value that satisfied the foreign key reference. But that's just a guess, because you haven't shown any examples of the data rows.

Comment: Yeah, that is the case. For some reason when displaying SELECT queries there's random '|' symbols in the output even when selecting only 5 rows. Although that sounds like a separate problem altogether, thank you for your help in all this.

Answer (score 1):

You can load the data into a temporary table that has no foreign key. Then use a `JOIN` with table A to insert into the real table B.

```
INSERT INTO B
SELECT tb.*
FROM tempB AS tb
JOIN TableA AS a on a.name = tb.sampleName
```